# En esta peticion http donde iria el async y el await

Tags: ajax, angular, api, http

queria obligar a esta funcion a ser asincrona, por ello le he pues el `async` pero el `await`, que lo estaba intentando poner en el **return** no me deja.

¿Donde deberia poner el `await`?

```
public async  loginU(usuario:string, password:string){
    return   this._http
    .get<Usuario>(this.URI+"/existU/"+usuario+"/"+password)
    .pipe(
      map(usuario=>{
        return    usuario;
      })
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

En realidad no va en ninguna parte. [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona) y [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) son para trabajar con promesas y los métodos de `HttpClient` lo que devuelven son [Observables](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html).

> La finalidad de las funciones async/await es simplificar el comportamiento del uso síncrono de promesas y realizar algún comportamiento específico en un grupo de Promises. Del mismo modo que las Promises son semejantes a las devoluciones de llamadas estructuradas, async/await se asemejan a una combinación de generadores y promesas.

Los observables son mucho más poderosos que las promesas ya que permiten, entre otras cosas cancelar la ejecución de la petición http, por lo que te recomiendo mantenerlas en lugar de cambiar a promesas.

En tu código quedaría:

```
public loginU(usuario:string, password:string){
    return this._http
        .get<Usuario>(this.URI+"/existU/"+usuario+"/"+password)
        .pipe(
            map(usuario=>{
                return    usuario;
            })
        )
}
```

Y en otra parte de tu código:

```
this.loginU(usuario, password).subscribe();
```

La parte `subscribe()` es la que [desencadena](https://angular.io/guide/observables#basic-usage-and-terms) la llamada http.

También podría ser:

```
public loginU(usuario:string, password:string){
    return this._http
        .get<Usuario>(this.URI+"/existU/"+usuario+"/"+password)
        .pipe(
            map(usuario=>{
                return    usuario;
            })
        ).subscribe();
}
```

Si lo quieres llamar directamente desde ese método.

Por cierto, escribir:

```
map(usuario=>{
    return    usuario;
})
```

No hará nada ya que `map` es una operación de transformación y tu estas devolviendo el valor del parámetro exactamente igual a como lo recibiste.

Imagino que lo que intentabas hacer en realidad era asignar el valor a una variable de tu componente y para eso no debes usar `map` sino `tap` que es el que te permite ejecutar efectos secundarios en la cadena de operadores del observable. Algo cómo esto:

```
usuario: any;

public loginU(usuario:string, password:string){
    return this._http
        .get<Usuario>(this.URI+"/existU/"+usuario+"/"+password)
        .pipe(
            tap(usuario=> {
                this.usuario = usuario;
            })
        ).subscribe();
}
```

Luego de ejecutada la petición la variable `usuario` que está disponible en el template porque es `public` tendrá el valor que necesitas.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94508/discussion-on-answer-by-devconcept-en-esta-peticion-http-donde-iria-el-async-y-e).

Answer (score 0):

¿Ese código es Angular?

Por lo que veo entiendo que _http es un objeto de tipo HttpClient.

Si fuera así entonces la función loginU ya es asíncrona y donde la estés llamando la tienes que hacer con un subscribe, no tienes necesidad de usar async/await en este caso.

Async/await se usa con promesas, pero en este caso estás haciendo una suscripción.

```
public loginU(usuario: string, password: string) {
  return this._http
    .get<Usuario>(this.URI + "/existU/" + usuario + "/" + password)
    .pipe(
      map(usuario => {
        return usuario;
      })
    )
}

loginU.subscribe(result => {
  this.usuario = result
})
```

Comment: eso mismo que has hecho he probado de mil maneras y no me esta funcionando

Comment: Tendrías que poner un poco más de código así puedo ver como estás haciendo la llamada.

Comment: es el mismo proyecto del cual ahs ocmentado ahora tambien en mi otra pregunta.